# Using Powershell, trigger an action if the most recent Event Log event is over one hour old

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-event-log

We have a server running our backup software, and the software has its own event log. I can retrieve the most recent event log entry with this command:

```
Get-EventLog EventLogName -ComputerName server.example.com -newest 1
```

That gives me results like this:

```
Index Time          EntryType   Source                InstanceID Message
----- ----          ---------   ------                ---------- -------
64292 Aug 13 15:51  Information BackupSoftware             29593 Transfer of 1096 KB...
```

What I'd like to do is trigger an action (say, launch a second script) if the timestamp of the most recent event is older than one hour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Event = Get-EventLog Application | ? { $_.Source -EQ 'BackupSoftware' } | Sort Time | Select -Last 1
If($Event.Time -LT (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)) 
{ 
     Do-Stuff 
}
```

That will find the most recent event in the Application log with a Source of "BackupSoftware".

```
$Event = Get-EventLog BackupSoftware | Sort Time | Select -Last 1
If($Event.Time -LT (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)) 
{ 
     Do-Stuff 
}
```

That will find the most recent event in a custom log named BackupSoftware regardless of source or EventId.

In both cases, the script will `Do-Stuff` if the event is more than an hour old.

Comment: Why not use `-newest 1` instead of sort/select?

Comment: @MikeShepard Yep! You certainly could do that. You could also use Get-WinEvent, or even Get-WmiObject win32_NTLogEvent! There are lots of ways to skin cats in Powershell. Bonus fun: Use Measure-Command to see which method completes the fastest!